# Why does Apache parse .htaccess if accessed through the main page and not through a VirtualHost?

Tags: htaccess, apache

I have two websites. One is hosted on `/var/www` (`www.example.com`) and the other is `/var/www/test` (`test.example.com`). The second is a VirtualHost.

I wrote a .htaccess (I'm using it to mod_rewrite), put it into `/var/www/test`, and enabled `AllowOverride all` on the `/var/www` `<Directory>`.

Yet, when I go to the webpage `www.example.com/test`, Apache processes it, while if I go to `test.example.com` it doesn't.

What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Do you have `Options +FollowSymLinks` on your `test.example.com` VirtualHost? What version of Apache are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Add `AllowOverride All` in the directory settings within the vhost and that should solve your issues.